# Sonar service stops after adding a plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm having an error running sonar-runner:

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.csharp.ndeps.sensor.NDepsSensor

But right after adding the sonar-csharp-ndeps-plugin-1.3 my sonar service stops.

When I restart the service it is working for +/- 5 seconds and stops again.
I am using Sonar 5.6 version. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: You should provide enough details to make this reproducible. Share your code (a minimal example, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your setup. May be some experts can guess what are you talking about, but for me as an average coder, this is too unclear. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube NDeps plugin has been deprecated for quite a long time now. So for sure it is not compatible at all with SonarQube 5.6 - which makes your startup fail.

Please always check the [Plugin Version Matrix](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/plugin-version-matrix.html) when you install or upgrade SonarQube, this will save you time.